# How to post news feed in facebook from my site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I have a site that allows a user to login using their facebook login id through a RPX system.  When the user posts a comment in my site, I want it to automatically post the comment on their facebook wall too.  How can I do this using Rails?
I've been learning the facebooker plugin for a couple of days and still can't figure out how to do it.
Are there any easy ways to do this? I got the user's facebook email and id from rpx and just want to post something on their news feed/wall, it is just this simple and it already caused me a headache on how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: FYI - Facebook doesn't allow your code to call facebook, only a facebook app to interact with the outside world.

Comment: That's not true. You can interact with a user's content on Facebook using Facebook Connect.

Comment: gkrdvl, did you get this working? Please see my post if you have any advice, thank you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393620/how-do-i-allow-visitors-on-my-site-to-share-my-photos-on-their-facebook-news-feed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, Facebook. You're in for some fun.

I'm not sure how RPX works. I know it abstracts the details so it can support multiple social networks.

I've gotten this working using standard Facebook Connect (not RPX). You need to ask the user for the `status_update` [extended permission](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permission). Once you get that, you can post status updates with [`Users.setStatus`](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.setStatus).

I recommend looking into the RPX documentation to see if they have something similar.

Comment: Thx lot Luke, I just realized that Facebook have 2 set of api, API Developer for application and API Connect for outer site, when I do googling with "How to post News Feed in facebook in rails" it always end up with Developer API solution. So thx once again Luke u lift up my headache :)

Answer (score 2):

If you will create an RSS feed for each user, that you will be able to use [Flog Blog](http://www.rss4lib.com/2007/08/flog_blog_rss_to_facebook.html) - Facebook RSS service. 
It's just a thought. Try it. might work...