# How do I allow visitors on my site to share my photos on their facebook news feed?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, api

How do I allow visitors on my site to share my photos, on their Facebook wall/news feed?

I see that there is a "share" or "like" option from Facebook but that seems to share the whole page.

I would like to have it so that each picture has a small Facebook icon next to it and when they click it, that specific image only is added to their Facebook news feed/wall.

My site is in ASP.NET 3.5 using C#. I can develop in C# so if that is a route to what I am trying to achieve that is fine.

I did see this question and answer:
[How to post news feed in facebook from my site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217925/how-to-post-news-feed-in-facebook-from-my-site)

Is this still the correct way to do this? Are there any examples of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at The Facebook [Open Graph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph), esp. if you're photos can have a page of their own, with meta tags in the head.

See (at the bottom of the Object Types section)

> Use article for any URL that represents transient content - such as a news article, blog post, photo, video, etc.

This may suit your needs (and should allow you to place a like button next to the image). If not, take a look through the facebook developers docs.