# How do I programmatically upload pictures to facebook?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, facebook

Ok, so here was my first question:
[How do I allow visitors on my site to share my photos on their facebook news feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393620/how-do-i-allow-visitors-on-my-site-to-share-my-photos-on-their-facebook-news-feed)

After implementing it I realized what I really want is to upload the image as a photo to their photo album.

How would I got about getting an image on my site, to upload to **their photo album**, when they click on a facebook icon next to the image?

Any thoughts at all are appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214300/upload-base64-image-facebook-graph-api/16439233#16439233

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen the .NET librarys available on codeplex.
They should allow this plus alot more task.

http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/

http://facebook.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is a [photo upload REST API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/photos.upload), maybe this is helpful?

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. It appears this is to upload an image already in a users album to my desk top.... "Uploads a photo owned by the specified user or the current session user and returns the new photo."

Comment: from the documentation page you cited: `Please note: We are in the process of deprecating the REST API, so if you are building a new application you shouldn't use this function. Instead use the Graph API and POST to the photos connection of the User object`